# App Mode cannot go on Live , it stays on development. Does someone know why?

Tags: android, ios, events, live

It says i have to Record a screencast showing how my app uses its current permissions.
But when i click on Submit Screeencast, nothing happens. I'm back on the dashboard.
I need help please because now that the App is not Live on Meta for Developers, my ads show no results.

Does someone know what to do ?

I tried to contact Meta but nothing happened